# Print URL of wishlist

Tags: wishlist

i want to create option for printing customer wishlist. I want to add at the bottom of wishlist link to printing page. It should execute Ctrl+P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript for it. Add an event "window.print();" on the print button at the bottom of wishlist page.